What is the most "empty" Linux system call to benchmark against?
I want to benchmark some performance aspects of a Linux device driver (a loadable module). Specifically, how fast certain code paths are when they are invoked from userspace via system calls.
In addition to measuring absolute times, I wanted to have a metric of how large given code path latency is relatively to the "speed of light" on a given host. I.e., how does my code stack against the shortest necessary path of the userspace ↔ kernel roundtrip?
I need to find which Linux system call does as little useful work as possible. In other words, I am looking for one for which its execution time is dominated by the userspace/kernel roundtrip latency.
Ideally, it should be a "stable" code path that is rarely delayed because of some additional data processing must be done.
At the same time, this system call should not be a shortcut into a libc or any other pure userspace wrapper, it must perform the honest roundtrip to kernel and back.
Do you have any suggestions?

I feel like getpid is traditionally used for this purpose.  I believe some versions of libc tried to cache the result so as to avoid the actual system call, but I think this feature was removed as there were too many ways that a changed pid (via fork and relatives) could be missed.

But other calls like that: getuid, getppid, etc, could work. They should just involve fetching a single integer from the task's data structure, which should be readily available (its address usually lives in a register).

Another idea would be to use a syscall with an obviously incorrect parameter (for example nanosleep with an out-of-range timespec). In that case the kernel should return early.

To avoid any libc shortcuts, you could invoke the system call directly using inline assembly

@perivesta: I would not use assembly, Just glibc generic calls (which just do handle the parameters and do the system call, i.e. do the assembly part for you and nothing more, and all as macro)

The shortest user-kernel round-trip is an invalid system call.  Like rax=-1 / syscall.  Fastest Linux system call.  (The kernel code used to dispatch directly from asm.  Now it goes through a C function, but still returning directly from that C function is going to be fastest.)

And BTW, you can use glibc's syscall(long number, ...) since it doesn't have a wrapper directly.  That will run a bit more code in user-space than a dedicated wrapper like getpid (e.g. mov instructions in case you passed 6 operands), but probably only another couple cycles vs. a syscall macro (e.g. from musl) if called in a loop.  Peanuts vs. Meltdown / Spectre mitigation on top of just getting the CPU into kernel mode and back.
